# How could I find the optimal paired values for given incidence matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matching-theory

I'm not a mathematician so it's possible that I'm using incorrect terminology here, but I'll try to explain.

Say I have an arbitrary evenly sized list of variables (for instance, A to H). Each of these variables has a value representing its relationship to each of the other variables individually. A variable cannot have a relationship with itself, so those values are represented as N/A. Below is a matrix showing the relationship between these example variables.

[Matrix of values relating to each pair of variables A through H.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjuPW.png)

Assuming that each variable cannot be paired with itself, and no variable can be paired with another variable twice, how could I find the 'optimal' pairs between each variable that would result in the highest (or lowest) total cumulative score? For instance, according to the above image:

- AB = 1
- CD = 1
- EF = 0
- GH = 1

Total score = 3

- AG = 9
- BF = 6
- CE = 8
- DH = 9

Total score = 32

It's possible that this problem is related to [Mutual Coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_coherence_(linear_algebra)), but I can't say that for sure since I'm having a bit of trouble comprehending that explanation of the concept.

Comment: What you describe is an incidence matrix.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a [maximum (or minimum) weighted matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)). There are a number of ways to solve this. The [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) is particularly helpful.

Comment: The Hungarian algorithm is for a bipartite graph.  The OP has a general graph, and the [Blossom algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) is applicable.